# Apache .htaccess Redirect 301 doesn't work with PDF link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use `Redirect` in `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
## Redirects
Redirect 301 /d1_tm1_location.html /d1_tm1_location.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm2_history.html /d1_tm2_history.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm3_articles.html /d1_tm3_articles.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm4_culture.html /d1_tm4_culture.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm5_economy.html /d1_tm5_economy.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm6_symbols.html /d1_tm6_symbols.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm7_gallery.html /d1_tm6_symbols.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm_civil.html /d1_tm6_symbols.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm_education.html /d1_tm6_symbols.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm_sport.html /d1_tm_sport.php
Redirect 301 /d1_tm_villages.html /d1_tm_villages.php
Redirect 301 /d2_ref1_phonebook.html /d2_ref1_phonebook.php
Redirect 301 /d2_ref_transport.html /d2_ref_transport.php
Redirect 301 /d3_ic1_services.html /d3_ic1_services.php
Redirect 301 /d3_ic_enterpreneur.html /d3_ic_enterpreneur.php
Redirect 301 /d3_ic_eservices.html /d3_ic_eservices.php
Redirect 301 /d3_ic_social.html /d3_ic_social.php
Redirect 301 /d3_ic_taxes.html /d3_ic_taxes.php
Redirect 301 /d4_adm1_structure.html /d4_adm1_structure.php
Redirect 301 /d4_adm2_contacts.html /d4_adm2_contacts.php
Redirect 301 /d4_adm5_strategy.html /d4_adm5_strategy.php
Redirect 301 /d4_adm6_budget.html /d4_adm6_budget.php
Redirect 301 /d4_adm7_registers.html /d4_adm7_registers.php
Redirect 301 /d4_adm_awards.html /d4_adm_awards.php
Redirect 301 /d5_mc1_composition.html /d5_mc1_composition.html
Redirect 301 /d5_mc2_regulations.html /d5_mc2_regulations.php
Redirect 301 /d6_prj1_current.html /d6_prj1_current.php

# >>> FAILS TO MATCH
Redirect 301 /adm_strategy/Strategia%20za%20zakrila%20na%20deteto%202007-2009.pdf /adm_strategy/Strategia%20za%20zakrila%20na%20deteto.pdf  

RedirectMatch 301 /buyerprofile/(.*)\.html$ /buyerprofile/$1.php
```

All redirects work properly, except rule for the PDF file. The old file was:

`http://www.lyaskovets.net/adm_strategy/Strategia%20za%20zakrila%20na%20deteto%202007-2009.pdf`

and the new one is:

`http://www.lyaskovets.net/adm_strategy/Strategia%20za%20zakrila%20na%20deteto.pdf`

`AllowOverride All` is placed in `httpd.conf` file.

I do not know whether the problem has something to do with that file type is PDF, or that the file name contains spaces, but this rule doesn't work.
Can someone help me with ideas where to search for the problem...

The situation is the same on two Apache servers:

**Linux:** *Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.lyaskovets.net Port 80*

**Windows:** *Apache/2.2.19 (Win64) PHP/5.3.5 Server at www1.lyaskovets.net Port 80*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /adm_strategy/Strategia%20za%20zakrila%20na%20deteto%202007-2009.pdf /adm_strategy/Strategia%20za%20zakrila%20na%20deteto.pdf
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against the %-decoded URL-path. (The `%20` is just the URL-encoded space in the original request.)

So, this should be rewritten as:

```
Redirect 301 "/adm_strategy/Strategia za zakrila na deteto 2007-2009.pdf" "/adm_strategy/Strategia za zakrila na deteto.pdf"
```

Surround the arguments in double quotes, since spaces are a *delimiter* (ie. special chararcter) in Apache config files.

Spaces in filenames/URLs are always best avoided if you can.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect